# What is the most efficient query pattern for overriding rows that have 'more specificity'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, architecture, publish-subscribe

I have a table that is going to represent subscriptions to notifications. It has to be generic enough to fit a large number of scenarios so it will contain an "All" flag of some kind, but I am constrained by brownfield architecture, so "All" needs to be in the form of an ID field being 0.

So I have a subscription table that looks like this (note that I'm using text in some places where there is actually integer IDs just for ease of reading):

```
+----------------+--------+---------+------------------+----------+
| SubscriptionID | UserID | GroupID | NotificationType | Viewable |
+----------------+--------+---------+------------------+----------+
|              1 |    Jim |       0 | Hello World      |        1 |
|              2 |      0 |     CEO | Hello World      |        0 |
|              3 |   Mary |       0 | Hello World      |        0 |
|              4 |      0 |       0 | Goodbye World    |        1 |
+----------------+--------+---------+------------------+----------+
```

Such that when I query for notifications for a specific customer, I can't just select all subscriptions for that ID as I would miss the "0" meaning "all" records (1 and 4) for users that do not override.

Right now my current code feels awfully inefficient and strange -

1. Dump all records that have Viewable 0 for that User/Group ID into one temp table ("Unsubscribed")
2. Dump all records that have Viewable 1 for that User/GroupID into one temp table ("Overrides")
3. Dump all records that have "All" and Viewable 1 minus the records from "Unsubscribed" and adding "Overrides" into a third temp table ("ValidSubscriptions")
4. Acquire notifications from the notification table that still fit based on NotificationType in "ValidSubscriptions"

It is this workflow above that seems strange to me, and highly inefficient (everything comes out to table scans in the execution plan, though this might just be what it has to be). Is there a better alternative to this clash of temp tables?

```
SELECT NotificationType
INTO #unsubscribed
FROM dbo.Subs
WHERE 
    UserID = @UserID
    AND IsEnabled=0


SELECT NotificationTypeID
INTO #override
FROM dbo.WIP_DashboardNotificationSubscription 
WHERE 
    UserID = @UserID
    AND IsEnabled=1


DECLARE @subscriptionTable TABLE ( --Use this syntax so that EF can determine the correct field types during import
    SubscriptionID uniqueidentifier,
    UserID int,
    NotificationType varchar(50),
    IsEnabled bit
)

INSERT INTO @subscriptionTable (SubscriptionID, UserID, NotificationType, IsEnabled)
SELECT SubscriptionID, DomainID, NotificationType, Decay, IsEnabled
FROM (
    SELECT SubscriptionID, DomainID, NotificationType, IsEnabled
    FROM dbo.WIP_DashboardNotificationSubscription
    WHERE
        DomainID = 0
        AND IsEnabled=1
        AND NotificationType NOT IN (SELECT NotificationType FROM #unsubscribed)    
        AND NotificationType NOT IN (SELECT NotificationType FROM #override)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM #override
) s

SELECT [Message], [Subscription].NotificationType, 
FROM @subscriptionTable [Subscription]
    INNER JOIN [NotificationPool] [Notification] ON [Subscription].[NotificationType]=[Notification].[NotificationType] AND ([Type].[UserID]=0 OR [Type].[UserID]=@UserID)
WHERE
    UserID IS NULL OR UserID=@UserID --AND userid
```

There are currently 3 tables -

- WIP_DashboardNotificationSubscription - Contains user subscriptions (per above)
- WIP_DashboardNotificationType - Contains type mapping information (notificationtype)
- WIP_DashboardNotificationPool - Contains the actual messages for the end users based on userid/groupid

Comment: With out knowing table densities,schema,it will be not possible to give a solution which may help you .Few suggestions

Comment: use temp table for @subscription table, if it has more than 1000 rows.Remove not in and replace it with not exists

Comment: I doubt that any individual combination of subscriptions will result in > 1000 rows, but I unfortunately need to maintain that syntax because of our ORM. Thanks for the `not exists` suggestion I'm looking into it and seeing the benefits!

Comment: @TheGameiswar I've added the tables I'm using above, but they are fairly simple and not worth getting too deep into the details of. The notificationpool will be optimized with clustered indexes on the group id because we service many different groups. The pool will be the main table, and will hold many many notifications which will be periodically cleaned out based on age, so we don't forsee a long term issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in one statement:

```
SELECT 
    userNotifications.NotificationType
FROM
    dbo.subs userNotifications
    LEFT JOIN dbo.subs disallowed ON
        viewable = 0 and
        (
            (groupid = 0 and 
                userid = 0 or userid = @userid
            ) or
            (userid= 0 and
                groupid = 0 or groupid = @groupid
            )
        )
WHERE
    disallowed.subscriptionid is null and
    (
        groupid = 0 and (
            userNotifications.userid = @UserId or
            usernotifications.userid = 0 
        ) or
        (userid = 0 and (
            usernotifications.groupid = @groupid or
            usernotifications.groupid = 0
        )
    )
```

This should use indexes as defined, and run quite quickly (assuming you have indexes set up on the relevant columns.